# Org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /root/web/report/read_monthly_scheme.jsp(322,20) equal symbol expected.

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am facing above problem..
The detail description is:
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message:

Description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /root/web/report/read_monthly_scheme.jsp(322,20) equal symbol expected
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:154)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:484)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTagFileDirectives(Parser.java:1784)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:127)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:120)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:165)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:332)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 logs.
```

Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

I tried to find out but I don't understand where is the problem..I have entered part of code below.
code is:

```
<%--
    Document   : rpt_monthly_schemewise
    Created on : Nov 1, 2012, 12:22:00 PM
    Author     : app.support
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="Conn.GEN_Utility"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <%
                //   String FromScheme = GEN_Utility.getAllListValues(request.getParameterValues("FromScheme"));
                //  String FromAsset = GEN_Utility.getAllListValues(request.getParameterValues("FromAsset"));

                String ToScheme = GEN_Utility.getAllListValues(request.getParameterValues("ToScheme"));
                String ToAsset = GEN_Utility.getAllListValues(request.getParameterValues("ToAsset"));

                String FromDt = request.getParameter("dtFrom");
                String ToDate = request.getParameter("dtTo");

                String AMC_Branch = GEN_Utility.getAllListValues(request.getParameterValues("lstBranch"));
                String ISC_Branch = GEN_Utility.getAllListValues(request.getParameterValues("lstBranchKarvy"));
                String Zone_Branch = GEN_Utility.getAllListValues(request.getParameterValues("lstZone"));
              //  out.println(" AMCBranch " + AMC_Branch + " ISC_Branch " + ISC_Branch + " Zone " + Zone_Branch);
                String query_s_FD = null;
                String sql_Total_net = null;
                String Show_ISC=request.getParameter("chkBranch");
                if(Show_ISC==null){
                    Show_ISC="OFF";
                    }

           //    out.println(" Show_ISC "+Show_ISC);

                //   out.println(" FromScheme " + FromScheme);
                //  out.println(" FromAsset " + FromAsset);
                //  out.println(" ToScheme " + ToScheme);
                //   out.println(" ToAsset " + ToAsset);
                //  out.println(" From Date " + FromDt + " To Date " + ToDate);
                String STRcon = "jdbc/mis";
///////////find date before 4 days of fromdate
                String StartDay = FromDt.substring(0, 2).trim();
                String StartMon = FromDt.substring(3, 6).trim();
                String StartYear = FromDt.substring(7, FromDt.length()).trim();



//logic for findning next 4 days fromcurrent Fromdt
                String[] months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

                int[] TotalDayS = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
                ///find index of StartMon
                int indexOfMonth = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {

                    if (StartMon.equals(months[i])) {
                        indexOfMonth = i;
                    }
                }
                int TotalDaysOFStartMonth = TotalDayS[indexOfMonth];
                int DecrementalVar = 4;
                int Previous_dt = 0;
                String Previous_month = "";
                int Previous_year = 0;
                String Pre_Date = "";
                //  System.out.print(" StartDAte "+StartDay+" deccemental "+DecrementalVar+" indexOfMonth "+indexOfMonth);


                if (DecrementalVar > Integer.parseInt(StartDay)) {
                    // System.out.print(" Inside 1st condition ");
                    if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 01 && !StartMon.equals(months[11]) && !StartMon.equals(months[0])) {
                        ////// date is 1 and month is not dec
                        Previous_dt = 26;
                        Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth - 1];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear);
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        //  System.out.println(" Pre_Date " + Pre_Date + " dtFrom " + FromDt);
                        //  System.out.print(" Inside 1st of 1st condition ");

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 1 && StartMon.equals(months[11])) {
                        ////// date is 1 and month is dec
                        Previous_dt = 26;
                        Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth - 1];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear) - 1;
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        //  System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 1 && StartMon.equals(months[0])) {
                        ////// date is 1 and month is dec
                        Previous_dt = 26;
                        Previous_month = months[11];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear) - 1;
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        //  System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    }
                    ////////////now for date 2////////////////

                    if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 2 && !StartMon.equals(months[11]) && !StartMon.equals(months[0])) {
                        ////// date is 2 and month is not dec
                        Previous_dt = 27;
                        Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth - 1];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear);
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        //  System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 2 && StartMon.equals(months[11])) {
                        ////// date is 2 and month is dec
                        Previous_dt = 27;
                        Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth - 1];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear) - 1;
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        //   System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 2 && StartMon.equals(months[0])) {
                        ////// date is 1 and month is dec
                        Previous_dt = 27;
                        Previous_month = months[11];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear) - 1;
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        //  System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 3 && !StartMon.equals(months[11]) && !StartMon.equals(months[0])) {
                        ////// date is 3 and month is not dec
                        Previous_dt = 28;
                        Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth - 1];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear);
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        // System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 3 && StartMon.equals(months[11])) {
                        ////// date is 3 and month is dec
                        Previous_dt = 28;
                        Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth - 1];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear) - 1;
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        //   System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 3 && StartMon.equals(months[0])) {
                        ////// date is 1 and month is dec
                        Previous_dt = 28;
                        Previous_month = months[11];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear) - 1;
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        //  System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    }


                } else if (DecrementalVar == Integer.parseInt(StartDay)) {

                    if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 4 && !StartMon.equals(months[11]) && !StartMon.equals(months[0])) {
                        ////// date is 3 and month is not dec
                        Previous_dt = 28;
                        Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth - 1];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear);
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        // System.out.println(" Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 4 && StartMon.equals(months[11])) {
                        ////// date is 3 and month is dec
                        Previous_dt = 28;
                        Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth - 1];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear) - 1;
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                     //   System.out.println(" Pre_Date " + Pre_Date + " dtFrom " + FromDt);

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(StartDay) == 4 && StartMon.equals(months[0])) {
                        ////// date is 3 and month is dec
                        Previous_dt = 28;
                        Previous_month = months[11];
                        Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear) - 1;
                        Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                        System.out.println(" Pre_Date " + Pre_Date + " dtFrom " + FromDt);

                    }



                } else if (DecrementalVar < Integer.parseInt(StartDay)) {


                    Previous_dt = Integer.parseInt(StartDay) - DecrementalVar;
                    Previous_month = months[indexOfMonth];
                    Previous_year = Integer.parseInt(StartYear);
                    Pre_Date = String.valueOf(Previous_dt) + "-" + Previous_month + "-" + String.valueOf(Previous_year);
                    // System.out.println("DecrementalVar< Integer.parseInt(StartDay)  Pre_Date "+Pre_Date+" dtFrom "+FromDt);






                }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // String Todate="25-Dec-2012";
                String To_StartDay = ToDate.substring(0, 2).trim();
                String To_StartMon = ToDate.substring(3, 6).trim();
                String To_StartYear = ToDate.substring(7, FromDt.length()).trim();


                int incrementVar = 4;
                int indexOfToDateMonth = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {

                    if (To_StartMon.equals(months[i])) {
                        indexOfToDateMonth = i;
                    }
                }
                int LastDate = Integer.parseInt(To_StartDay) + incrementVar;
                String LastMon = "";
                String LastYear = "";
                int DiffOfDays = TotalDayS[indexOfToDateMonth] - LastDate;
                String Last_Day = "";
                if (TotalDayS[indexOfToDateMonth] > LastDate) {

                    LastMon = To_StartMon;
                    LastYear = To_StartYear;
                    Last_Day = String.valueOf(LastDate) + "-" + LastMon + "-" + LastYear;
                } else if (DiffOfDays == 0) {
                    LastDate = TotalDayS[indexOfToDateMonth];
                    LastMon = To_StartMon;
                    LastYear = To_StartYear;
                    Last_Day = String.valueOf(LastDate) + "-" + LastMon + "-" + LastYear;

                } else if (0 > DiffOfDays) {
                    if (To_StartMon.equals("Dec")) {
                        LastDate = DiffOfDays * -1;
                        LastMon = months[0];
                        LastYear = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(To_StartYear) + 1);
                        Last_Day = String.valueOf(LastDate) + "-" + LastMon + "-" + LastYear;



                    } else {
                        LastDate = DiffOfDays * -1;
                        LastMon = months[indexOfToDateMonth + 1];
                        LastYear = To_StartYear;
                        Last_Day = String.valueOf(LastDate) + "-" + LastMon + "-" + LastYear;



                    }


                }
///////////////logic for gettting next 10 days from Todate///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ////////logic for getting next 10th day from search date///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                int incrementVarBy10 = 10;
                //  String  Last_Day10="";
                int LastDate10 = Integer.parseInt(To_StartDay) + incrementVarBy10;
                String LastMon10 = "";
                String LastYear10;
                int DiffOfDays10 = TotalDayS[indexOfToDateMonth] - LastDate10;
                String Last_Day10 = "";

                if (TotalDayS[indexOfToDateMonth] > LastDate10) {

                    LastMon10 = To_StartMon;
                    LastYear10 = To_StartYear;
                    Last_Day10 = String.valueOf(LastDate10) + "-" + LastMon10 + "-" + LastYear10;
                } else if (DiffOfDays10 == 0) {
                    LastDate10 = TotalDayS[indexOfToDateMonth];
                    LastMon10 = To_StartMon;
                    LastYear10 = To_StartYear;
                    Last_Day10 = String.valueOf(LastDate10) + "-" + LastMon10 + "-" + LastYear10;

                } else if (0 > DiffOfDays10) {
                    if (StartMon.equals("Dec")) {
                        LastDate10 = DiffOfDays10 * -1;
                        LastMon10 = months[0];
                        LastYear10 = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(To_StartYear) + 1);
                        Last_Day10 = String.valueOf(LastDate10) + "-" + LastMon10 + "-" + LastYear10;



                    } else {
                        LastDate10 = DiffOfDays10 * -1;
                        LastMon10 = months[indexOfToDateMonth + 1];
                        LastYear10 = To_StartYear;
                        Last_Day10 = String.valueOf(LastDate10) + "-" + LastMon10 + "-" + LastYear;

                    }


                }

                //   out.println(" pre date  " + Pre_Date + " Last DAy " + Last_Day + " Last_day10 " + Last_Day10);
%>
    <%
///////////////////delete from Temp_MonthlyReport///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                String query_del_temp = "delete from Ekarvy.Temp_monthlyReport";
                Connection conn_del_temp = GEN_Utility.getConnection(STRcon);
                PreparedStatement ps_del_temp = conn_del_temp.prepareStatement(query_del_temp);
                ps_del_temp.executeUpdate();
                //   out.println("From Scheme " + FromScheme + " To Scheme " + ToScheme);
                conn_del_temp.close();
                ps_del_temp.close();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ///////////////////////////////////////insert data into temp_DailyReport/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                String sql = "insert into Ekarvy.Temp_monthlyReport(REFNO,FUND,SCHEME,SCHPLAN,ACNO,BRANCH,TRNO,RECDT,TRDT,PROCESSDT,BATCHCLOSEDT,AMT,UNITS,NAV,POP,TRTYPE,BROKER,"
                        + "SUBBROKER,REMARKS,BACKDATEDREASON,APPLNO,CHQNO,CHQDT,CHQBANK,CHQTYPE,CHQCLEAREDDT,"
                        + "LOADAMT,LOADPER,INWARDNO,PURRED,ATMCARDNO,USER_ID,DT_UPDATE,OLD_BRANCH)"
                        + "select a.REFNO,a.FUND,a.SCHEME,a.SCHPLAN,a.ACNO,a.BRANCH,a.TRNO,a.RECDT,a.TRDT,a.PROCESSDT,a.BATCHCLOSEDT,a.AMT,a.UNITS,a.NAV,a.POP,a.TRTYPE,a.BROKER,"
                        + "a.SUBBROKER,a.REMARKS,a.BACKDATEDREASON,a.APPLNO,a.CHQNO,a.CHQDT,a.CHQBANK,a.CHQTYPE,a.CHQCLEAREDDT,"
                        + "a.LOADAMT,a.LOADPER,a.INWARDNO,a.PURRED,a.ATMCARDNO,a.USER_ID,a.DT_UPDATE,a.BRANCH from EKARVY.VW_DATA_TRAN a where a.trdt between '" + Pre_Date + "' and '" + Last_Day10 + "'";

                Connection con = null;

                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                ////remove this STRconwhere import <%@ include file="/vw_chksession.jsp"

                try {
                    con = GEN_Utility.getConnection(STRcon);
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                    //   out.println(sql);

                    ps.executeQuery();
                    con.close();
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    out.println(" Error at Inserting values in Temp_monthlyReport " + e);
                }
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////UPDATE  FOR
```

Comment: try { //322
                    con = GEN_Utility.getConnection(STRcon);
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                    //   out.println(sql);

                    ps.executeQuery();
                    con.close();
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    out.println(" Error at Inserting values in Temp_monthlyReport " + e);
                }
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////UPDATE  FOR

Comment: rohit jain : please help me where is the problem

Comment: @Sumit.. First of all, you should change `ps.executeQuery();` to `ps.executeUpdate();` in that `try-catch` block. You are doing insertion right?

Comment: @okay rohit will change this line....do u think the problem is because of this?

Comment: @Sumit.. Your `insert` query is literally crying for help. Check it's syntax. You have mixed up `INSERT` and `SELECT`. Were you trygin to use nested query?

Comment: @rohit: actually i want to insert more or less 28110 records(one month data) in temp_monthlyreport for that i used select query for insertion

Comment: Hey I got the solution... above to this try catch block i wrote the comment( ////remove this STRconwhere import <%@ include file="/vw_chksession.jsp") .i removed this comment..now code works properly....